# Read fixed size register with spaces from file

Tags: c, file, scanf

Im trying to read a fixed size register from a  text file in c.

The structure of the register is the following:

> 00030REGIST X1Y005.0

- 5 characters for an integer
- 10 characters for an string(with spaces)
- 5 characters for a float

When I try to read the register, I get the following result:

> 00030REGIST X1Y005.00.00000

I get a 0.00000 at the end of the string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () { 
    int id;
    float price;
    char desc[11];
    FILE * data_file;

    //Reading from file
    if(!(data_file = fopen("./products.txt","r"))){
        printf("\nError reading file\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    // The value of the register is 00030REGIST X1Y005.0
    // But i get                    00030REGIST X1Y005.00.00000
    while (fscanf(data_file,"%05d %[^\n]10s %05f", &id, desc, &price) != EOF) {
        printf("%05d%s%05f\n",id , desc, price);
    }

    fclose(data_file);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `%[]` (character group or set) conversion specifier is its own thing, it's not a modifier to the `%s` (string) specifier. This seems to be a common misconception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I changed the program to read 10 string characters which can include digits.

The format specifier `%[^\n]10s` is a strange hybrid of `%s` and `%[]`. I suggest the following, here just a single string for the sake of an example, and newlines added to the output for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int id;
    float price;
    char desc[11];
    char input[] = "00030REGIST X1Y005.0";
    int res = sscanf(input, "%d%10[^\n]%f", &id, desc, &price);
    if(res == 3) {
        printf("%05d\n%s\n%05f\n",id , desc, price);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
00030
REGIST X1Y
5.000000
```

Comment: What if i want numbers in REGISTER XVY. REGISTER X15 for example?

Comment: Please add that possibility to the question. Note the question says 10 characters. Do you want it to be truncated or is that a mistake?

Comment: Sorry it is a mistake.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia you've shortened the target string to 10 now. Is the 12 of `REGISTER X1Y` a fixed field width or not?

Comment: It is 10 sorry.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia I edited again with your revised data. I used `sscanf` for the sake of the example, obviously you will use `fscanf`.

Comment: @MiguelGarcia: Please think about your question before you ask it, and get the details right, because it is damned hard work dealing with Chameleon Questions.  Once you get answers, you should not modify your question to invalidate the answers you've been given.  Until there are answers, fixups are OK, but once you have answers, further modifications that break the answers, or that ask for extra information, are not fair to those who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
while (fscanf(data_file,"%05d %[^\n]10s %05f", &id, desc, &price) != EOF)
```

You probably need:

```
while (fscanf(data_file,"%5d %40[^\n0-9] %5f", &id, desc, &price) == 3)
```

The `40` is based on the size of `desc` (you specify one less in the format string than in the length declared for the array).  Note that a scan set `%[…]` is a conversion on its own.  The `10s` in your version is looking for the specific characters `1`, `0`, and `s` (and that will fail — the next character would be a newline or end-of-file because you didn't specify a size for the scan set).  And the test should be for the expected number of conversions; anything else is an error of some sort.

If register names can contain digits, you're hosed because `REGISTER XVY` is 12 characters counting the space (which contradicts your claim that register names are up to 10 characters).  Specifying any smaller value than 12 in `%12[^\n0-9]` won't convert that name and the following number because it will leave non-numeric characters in the input.

If you must have digits in the register name, you have to adopt a different strategy.  You'd read the line, then strip the leading 5 digit number and convert that, strip the trailing 5 digit number and convert that, and take what's left as the register name, possibly stripping leading and trailing blanks.

Comment: The question has morphed several times in terms of the content and length of the register name (and the size of the `desc` variable).  Originally, the example data didn't match the claimed lengths.  This answer worked around that — one of many possible ways.  Now the question is somewhat different — the core of this answer remains valid but the details need tweaking during daylight hours.  But they shouldn't need tweaking; the question should not be modified to invalidate answers after any answers are given.  Be complete and careful when asking the question in the first place.  Think!